# Getting data from backend and sending data to databse through node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm working on the front end of an application, the backend has been built in `Spring Boot` and `MongoDB`, I want to use a javascript library that provides chat functionality `sockets.io` and from examples I've seen, generally `mongo` is accessed via `node` and `express`. So what I was thinking was, getting usernames and such from the `spring boot` backend and then send data to my database (the messages) through `node` and `express`. Is something like this doable/recommended?

Comment: It is doable but why split your backend into 2? either write it all in spring or write it all in node.

Comment: please take a look https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-server-java